How does Conda/Mamba make SSL files?
Context
I was trying to update a variable for SSL so that it wouldn't try using old ciphers. To do this, I found I needed to add a minProtocal variable to my openssl.cnf. To figure out where that file was I ran open_ssl version -d (*Note: 'version' is a command, not a switch/flag.) This output OPENSSLDIR: "/home/<user>/miniforge3/envs/li/ssl". Clearly this instance of ssl is unique to my mamba environment then. To be sure it isn't a symlink, I run ls -l | grep "openssl.cnf" and get this output:
-rw-rw-r-- 4 <user> <user>  12395 Jul  3 16:07 openssl.cnf

I add the necessary code to this file in a random spot that doesn't interfere with anything else, save it, reload the Mamba environment, and my motivating error was solved.
The Plot Thickens...
To avoid this happening again, I decide to change the root's template for SSL that I assume Mamba copies. I deactivate all Mamba environments and again run openssl version -d to get the location, go to that directory (/usr/lib/ssl/), run ls -l | grep "openssl.cnf" and get:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Feb 16 15:41 openssl.cnf -> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

It's a symlink, so I go to the actual file and add the same code to openssl.cnf, but I stick it closer to the top, as that seemed like a more sensible place for it. To test this, I create a new Mamba env and go look at its openssl.cnf file and make sure it has the added code. It's not a symlink (still), so I infer there's been some sort of deep copy. Yet when I look in the file, the new code is added in the same randomly-chosen spot as the first mamba environment, not at the top as with the edited root's openssl.cnf. In other words, it copied the other Mamba-specific file, not the one that I thought it would copy from in /etc/ssl/.
I notice in /home/<user>/miniforge/ssl there is also an openssl.cnf, but this does not carry the changes made to the 1st Mamba env that propagated to the second, so I don't think it's copying from this Conda/Mamba-install either.
Question
Where/how does Mamba get the openssl.cnf file when creating a new environment? And subsequently how can I change the template to include my code, ideally for all users on the machine?
Other details

I have root privileges
Ubuntu == 20.04 LTS
OpenSSL (in Mamba env) == OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024)
OpenSSL (not in Mamba env) == OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

[Edit: Maybe this is useful info too(?), but opening a root terminal (sudo -i) and running the following:
source <user>/.bashrc
mamba create -n foo
mamba activate foo
openssl version -d

outputs:
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"

Which we've seen is just a symlink to /etc/ssl/, at least as far as openssl.cnf` is concerned. So the root terminal does not use Mamba's ssl, when creating/activating an env. Maybe that's relevant, maybe it's another SO post.
